# How can I get back uncommitted files?

Tags: git

was coding on the development branch and  when everything looked perfect I decided to commit my changes. However, I did not follow the path I always follow, which is:

1. `git add .`
2. `git commit -m "commit message"`

Instead, I did this:

```
git commit -a -m"commit message"
```

and pushed changes to the remote branch (development). Later, I found out that some folders and files that I had created were gone, and those were the most crucial parts of the new version of my project. I checked out to that commit (I did not make any local changes after that), but it did not work. Any advice?

Comment: can you please add a description of what happened *after* your `git commit -a` ? `git commit -a` didn't track the file you expected to track, but it certainly didn't delete them from the disk.

Did you run some other git actions ? some script ?

Comment: for example : if after this action, you checked out another branch, and ran `git add . ; git commit ...`, then your files should be on that other branch

Answer (score 2):

The thing about `git commit -a` is that it ignores untracked files. So if you created a new file, it didn't get committed when you said that. Since the file was never committed to Git's care, Git doesn't have a copy of it and is not responsible for it in any way. Therefore, depending on what happened such that "some folders and files that I had created were gone", they may be gone forever.

Comment: In my personal opinion, this is why commands like `git commit -a` are bad. Sure, they can be convenient. But you are robbing yourself of the opportunity to check, before committing, what is going into that commit — and what isn't. In my life, the convenience is not worth the risk. I like to tell Git what I want. As jonrsharpe has said recently, be more intentful when you talk to Git. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68923273/how-to-commit-and-push-a-file-only-once#comment121807768_68923273 (a great comment with a great link).

Answer (score 1):

You didn't commit the files to git (git was never told to track them), and you deleted them. Git can't do anything to help you. Your files are gone unless you have some other backups or undelete facility.

Answer (score 0):

[`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) will show you a history of the commits you've created and branches you've moved to.
E.g., from one of my demo projects:

```
mureinik@computer ~/src/git/gitdemo (new_branch)
c211146 (HEAD -> new_branch) HEAD@{0}: rebase (continue) (finish): returning to refs/heads/new_branch
c211146 (HEAD -> new_branch) HEAD@{1}: rebase (continue): removed file2.txt
069f49e (b1) HEAD@{2}: rebase (start): checkout b1
949bba7 HEAD@{3}: commit: removed file2.txt
8351298 HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from 8351298b995894e0483614b8ae9ed432de200e4b to new_branch
8351298 HEAD@{5}: checkout: moving from b1 to 8351298b995894e0483614b8ae9ed432de200e4b
069f49e (b1) HEAD@{6}: commit: added another line to file2.txt
8351298 HEAD@{7}: checkout: moving from master to b1
218f895 (master) HEAD@{8}: checkout: moving from b1 to master
8351298 HEAD@{9}: commit: Added file2.txt
218f895 (master) HEAD@{10}: checkout: moving from master to b1
218f895 (master) HEAD@{11}: commit: commit 100
```

On the left-most column, you'll see the commit hashes. If you can identify the last good commit hash (e.g., by using `git show <commit>` to see its contents, you can then check it out and create a branch from it, or even `git reset` your development branch to it.

Comment: That doesn't help if they didn't ever commit the files, though - `-a` won't have included files that weren't already tracked.